# Can I / How to Implement IEnumerable on third party object to Sort...just use LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

My last two question have had down votes so my apologies in advance if this is a dumb question and a waste of your time.

I am wanting to sort a collection on a property called CreateDate so I thought I would do something like:

```
MyList.Sort(x => x.CreateDate)
```

However MyList.Sort() is not available since MyList is a Microsoft DataCollection object that does NOT implement IEnumerable.

The Microsoft DataCollection from the metadata is as such:

```
public class DataCollection<T> : Collection<T>
{

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> items);
    public void AddRange(params T[] items);
    public T[] ToArray();
}
```

So the only two options I can think of are:

Use Linq something along these lines:

```
var query = from xyz in self.Entities
   orderby xyz.Attributes["CreateDate"]
   select xyz;
```

or cast to a list but then I have to create a comparer and I'm not sure how to get it back without iterating over the whole thing and rebuilding the DataCollection.

```
List<Entity> x = self.Entities.ToList();
x.Sort(y => y.Attributes["CreateDate"], comparer)
foreach(var x in x)
{
  //iterate and rebuild the DataCollection
}
```

Any input / critical evaluation would be appreciated

Thank You

Comment: `Collection<T>` does implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Both of those seem like valid solutions; which one you choose depends on how you're going to use the result. If you're just going to iterate it once, I'd use LINQ orderby solution. If you want to keep the result around and iterate over it many times, I'd use the ToList / Sort solution.

Comment: @Lee...Was my question poorly worded? Collection<T> does not implement IEnumerable<T>...I agree 100% thus my question??

Comment: @user1278561, It does. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: OHHHHH!!! My eyes were tricking me. It does implement is what @Lee said...well howdy do. I need to do me some learning.

Comment: @user1278561: `Sort` is not a Linq method. In Linq it is called `OrderBy`

Comment: OK So I just wrote this: self.Entities.OrderBy(x => x.Attributes["CreateDate"]);..so @Lee you should turn your comment into an answer so I can give credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure there's enough information here to accurately diagnose the problem, but I'll give it a shot.  I see two potential problems:

1. You're missing the reference to either `System.Linq` or `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`.
2. You need to cast the `DataCollection` to the correct type, using `MyList.Cast<Entity>().OrderBy(x => x.CreateDate)`

Also, note the use of `.OrderBy()` instead of `.Sort()`